# Linking UITableView with a NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I've been trying to fill a UITableView with data from a NSMutableArray. I have a View-Based application project and so far I've tried every tutorial I found but so far, it just doesn't work. I linked the dataSource and delegate to the File's Owner, I added the procotols UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource to my UIViewController, I create an array containing 3 strings just to try and debug, everytime I load the app, the table stays empty.

I'm not sure what could be my error, or where I should look to find the problem, if you guys got any idea that would be nice.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post some code for me?

Answer (score 1):

```
-(NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection: (NSInteger)section
{
    return [yourArray count];    
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellIdentifier";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }


    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [yourArray objectAtIndex:row];

    return cell;
}
```

That should populate the table from an array.  I've used it several times in my app.

Comment: In the future, please refrain from using tabs in your posts, as they do not work well with the code formatting here at stack overflow. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you did forget to call `-reloadData` on the table view.

Comment: Why would he need to call reloadData if its a table that should be loaded when the application loads?

Comment: I don't understand your point. If you want a table to be populated with data, you just have to call `reloadData` to invoke the data source methods.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the dataSource and delegate are properly connected to the view controller, also make sure your UITableView is property connected with the outlet if you are using storyboards or a xib file.

If nothing works I recommend you to use [XLData](https://github.com/xmartlabs/xldata) that makes UITableView data loading much more simple to implement.